# Что такое метка в JavaScript и как она работает?

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

Не так давно наткнулся на такой кусок кода:

```js
javascript:console.log('Пример какого-то текста')
```

Случайно изменив название `javascript` я заметил что код, как работал, так и работает, вот несколько примеров использования:

```js
привет: console.log(42)

$$$ :console.info('Некоторая информация')

abc123:(4 + 4) / 2 // Не обязательно выводить в консоль

abc:def:ghi:69 // Можно писать множество раз

window:window
```

Как вы видите не обязательно писать `javascript:` с левой части чтобы код запустился. Также я заметил что значение, которое пишется слева, должно иметь валидное название как у переменных. То-есть если оно будет начинаться с числа или будет содержать какой-то символ, который не разрешён для использования в переменных, то будет ошибка (то-есть название должно быть валидным идентификатором). А справа от `:` должно быть какое-то воспроизводимое выражение.

Примеры с кодом, где получается ошибка:

```
123:456
// Получаем ошибку:
// Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

@o@:console.log(42)
// Получаем ошибку:
// Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character

'window':69
// Получаем ошибку:
// Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

window:window:window // Почему получается ошибка?
// Получаем ошибку:
// Uncaught SyntaxError: duplicate label
```

Так какое же предназначение у такого синтаксиса? Какое у него есть применение? Какие есть неправильные и правильные способы применения? Какие могут произойти ошибки в при использовании меток, почему они происходят?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как оказалось это так называемые метки (`label`'ы). Они используются вместе с операторами `break` и `continue`. Сами метки являются неким аналогом `goto` из других ЯП.

### Синтаксис

```js
label :
  statement
```

- `label` (метка)

Как было отмечено в вопросе, слово использованное для метки должно быть валидным словом для переменной, то есть быть валидным [идентификатором](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#identifiers). Также слово не должно быть [ключевым словом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) или зарезервированным словом. Стоит также отметить что идентификатор метки должен быть уникальным для своего блока кода, иначе будет ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: duplicate label`.

Примеры *неправильного* кода с использованием ключевых слов.

```js
for:console.log('hello') // Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ( after for

return:console.log('world') // Uncaught SyntaxError: return not in function

void:console.log(42) // Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'
```

Пример *неправильного* кода с использованием зарезервированного слова.

```js
enum:console.log('hello') // Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got reserved word 'enum'
```

Пример *неправильного* кода с использованием идентичных идентификаторов.

```js
label1:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  label1: // Uncaught SyntaxError: duplicate label
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    console.log('inner', j)
  }
  console.log('outer', i)
}
```

При этом если они расположены отдельно, то их применение разрешено.

```js
label1:
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i)
  }

label1:
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i)
  }
```

- `statement` (выражение)

Это JavaScirpt выражение. `break` может быть использовано в любом блочном выражении, а вот `continue` только в [циклах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements#%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) (Для примера: `for`, `while`, `for...in` и т.п.).

Пример *неправильного* кода с использованием `continue` вне цикла.

```js
let i = 0

loop: {
  console.log(i)

  if(i < 10) {
    i++
    continue loop // SyntaxError: continue must be inside loop
  }
}
```

### Внимание!

В строгом режиме использовать слово `let` в качестве идентификатора для метки запрещено.

```js
'use strict';

let:
  console.log('hello')
```

Также стоит отметить что в строгом режиме нельзя использовать функции в качестве выражения. Об этом написано [в документации ECMAScript 2015-го года](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-labelled-function-declarations) (6-я версия ES).

> ##### Labelled Function Declarations
>
> Prior to ECMAScript 2015, the specification of *LabelledStatement* did not allow for the association of a statement label with a *FunctionDeclaration*. However, a labelled *FunctionDeclaration* was an allowable extension for non-[strict code](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code) and most browser-hosted ECMAScript implementations supported that extension. In ECMAScript 2015, the grammar productions for *LabelledStatement* permits use of *FunctionDeclaration* as a *LabelledItem* but [13.13.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-labelled-statements-static-semantics-early-errors) includes an Early Error rule that produces a Syntax Error if that occurs. For web browser compatibility, that rule is modified with the addition of the underlined text:
>
> *LabelledItem* : *FunctionDeclaration*
>
> - It is a Syntax Error if any strict mode source code matches this rule.

Перевод:

> ##### Объявления отмеченных функций
>
> В прошлой ECMAScript до 2015 года, в спецификации о *LabelledStatement* не было разрешено асоциировать выражение метки с *FunctionDeclaration*. Однако, отмеченный *FunctionDeclaration* был разрешённым расширением для не-[строгого кода](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code) и в основном реализации ECMAScript замещённый в браузере поддерживают это расширение. В ECMAScript 2015, грамматические производства для *LabelledStatement* разрешают использование *FunctionDeclaration* как *LabelledItem*, но [13.13.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-labelled-statements-static-semantics-early-errors) включает раннюю ошибку (Early Error) для этого и вызывает синтаксическую ошибку (Syntax Error), если это имеет место быть. Для совместимости веб-браузером, это правило было модифицированно текущим подчёркнутым текстом:
>
> *LabelledItem* : *FunctionDeclaration*
>
> - Это является синтаксической ошибкой (Syntax Error), если любой исходный код в строгом режим подходит под это правило.

```js
'use strict';

label:
  function someFn() {
  }
```

Не простые функции, такие как функции генераторы и асинхронные функции не могут быть отмечены ни в строгом и ни в не-строгом коде. Об этом написано [в MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#labeled_function_declarations):

> Non-plain functions, such as generator functions and async functions can neither be labeled in strict code, nor in non-strict code

```js
label:
  function* someGenFn() { // SyntaxError: generator functions cannot be labelled
  }
```

### Примеры

- `continue`

Пропустить текущую итерацию ВЕРХНЕГО цикла если `i` и `j` равны одному.

```js
loop1:
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  loop2:
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if(i === 1 && j === 1) {
      continue loop1
    }

    console.log('i =', i + '; j =', j)
  }
}
```

**Заметьте! Пропало не только `i = 1; j = 1`, но также `i = 1; j = 2` т.к. мы пропустили итерацию цикла *for i*.** То-есть если бы мы использовали просто `continue`, то был бы пропуск только `i = 1; j = 1` т.к. мы бы пропустили итерацию *for j*.

- `break`

Прерываем цикл *for i* если `i` и `j` равны одному

```js
loop1:
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  loop2:
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if(i === 1 && j === 1) {
      break loop1
    }

    console.log('i =', i + '; j =', j)
  }
}
```

**Опять же, обратите внимание на то что мы прерываем цикл *for i*, а не *for j*.** Это значит что если бы мы использовали просто `break`, прервался бы только цикл *for j*.

Как уже было упомянуто, `break` можно использовать *не* только в циклах, а ещё и в [блоках](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), вот пример:

```js
example: {
  console.log('Hello')

  break example

  console.log('This is secret message!')
}

console.log('World!')
```

Под конец также стоит упомянуть почему работают те выражения которые написаны в вопросе. Всё потому что это так называемые [expession statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Expression_statement)'ы и они разрешены для использования в качестве `statement` (см. синтаксис). Именно поэтому мы можем там написать даже математическое выражение и ничего страшного в этом не будет.

```js
let x = 0
let obj = {
  x: 42,
}

// В expression statements входят:

label:console.log(2 + 2) // Вызовы функций
label:`hello world` // Шаблонные литералы
label:x = 2 // Операции присваивания
label:4 * 4 // Операции по уменьшению/увеличению
label:4 + 4 // Операции по уменьшению/увеличению (x2)
label:delete obj.x // Удаление
// label:import { CONSTANT } from './my_constant.js' // Импортирование (здесь не получится показать)

function* genFn() {
  label:yield x // yield и yield*
}
```

### Источники

- [MDN на русском](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)
- [MDN на английском](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)
- [Спецификация ECMAScript 2015](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-labelled-function-declarations)

#### Найденный материал в процессе поиска на Stack Overflow (английском)

- [Is using labels in JavaScript bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906762/)
- [Labeled statements / gotos in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71487268/)
- [Ответ на вопрос: What's the best way to break from nested loops in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183161/183197#183197)
- [Ответ на вопрос: How to break nested loops in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1564818/1564838#1564838)

Comment: секция про использование меток с функциями (и генераторами) полностью неверная (включая перевод и примеры) за исключением прямой цитаты спецификации.

Comment: @Grundy `секция про использование меток с функциями полностью неверная` - а что именно не верно в этой секции? Вроде бы информация верная, ошибки тоже.. Что же не так?

Comment: В цитате спецификации явно указано, что именно нельзя использовать. У тебя же указано про все функции (и генераторы).

Comment: @Grundy может быть я и не выспался, но не вижу никаких проблем, я написал что функции нельзя использовать в качестве выражения в строгом режиме, об этом же написано в документации. То же написано в переводе цитаты, а про генераторы я вообще из MDN взял.

Comment: _функции нельзя использовать в качестве выражения в строгом режиме_ - это неверно, в спецификации совсем не это написано.

Comment: Ты даешь ссылку на автоперевод MDN, посмотри исходный текст, он совсем про другое.

Comment: @Grundy да вы правы, там совершенно другой текст. Сейчас изменю ответ.